# WPF application | Text Box Not Accepting "0" at start of Fax Number

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this application Developed by previous developer in this company.

Now i am trying to do some little fixes.

Here is a TextBox not accepting "0" at start.

i mean a fax number can be 0912258685 but problem is text box gets the "912258685" but not the "0" at the very beginning.

here is below code for that text box.

```
            <TextBox x:Name="tbFax" Height="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,87,0"
                     Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=FaxNo,
                            ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" TextChanged="tbFax_TextChanged"/>
```

some CS code Below. AS this TextBox is optional. so used this below code.

```
          if(!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbFax.Text)))
            {
                try
                {
                    //fax = int.Parse(tbFax.Text.Trim());
                    fax = Int64.Parse(tbFax.Text);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
              }
```

some of the rest of the code is below.

```
try
                    {
                        if (!(CheckAlreadyExist(tbName.Text.Trim().ToString())))
                        {
                            AgentAccount dtAgent = new AgentAccount();
                            dtAgent.Name = tbName.Text;
                            dtAgent.ContactNo = Int64.Parse(tbContactNo.Text);
                            dtAgent.Address = tbAddress.Text;
                            dtAgent.City = cmbCity.Text;
                            dtAgent.Country = cmbCountry.Text;
                            dtAgent.Balance = balance;
                            dtAgent.AccStatus = "Active";
                            dtAgent.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
                            dtAgent.Fax  = fax;
                            dtAgent.email = tbEmail.Text;
                            dtAgent.GbBranchId = GlobalClass.GbBranchID;

                            dc.AgentAccounts.InsertOnSubmit(dtAgent);
                            dc.SubmitChanges();
                            newAgentId = dtAgent.AgentID;
                            dc.SubmitChanges();

                            string messageBoxText = "Account Created Successfully\n Your Account No = '" + newAgentId +
                                                            "'\nDo You Want to take Receipt! ";
                            string caption = "Agent";
                            MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.YesNo;
                            MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.Warning;

                            string result = MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon).ToString();
                            if (result == "Yes")
                            {
                                GetPrint(newAgentId);
                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }

                            tbName.Text = "";
                            tbContactNo.Text = "";
                            tbAddress.Text = "";
                            tbFax.Text = "";
                            tbEmail.Text = "";
                            cmbCity.SelectedIndex = -1;
                            cmbCountry.SelectedIndex = -1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string msgtext = "Agent with same name already exist. You can't create same agent twice. Try with Different name!";
                            string caption = "Error";
                            MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.OK;
                            MessageBoxImage image = MessageBoxImage.Error;
                            MessageBox.Show(msgtext, caption, button, image).ToString();
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                    }
```

Do i need to change in above code or do i need to see in other stuff also for it.??

**Info :**

I cant input 0 in the form. i mean even i try to keep pressing 0, it just do not appear at the begging like my zero button is disabled or something.
so i think its not the problem with the save button, but actually form. I am not sure as i am not really an experience developer in .NET.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

**UPDATE**

I think this Event Handler is responsible, but also not sure as ContactNo is working fine..

```
private void tbFax_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ValidateInputIntegerTextBox(sender);
}

private void tbContactNo_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{

    ValidateInputIntegerTextBox(sender);
}
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    Int32 selectionStart = textBox.SelectionStart;
    Int32 selectionLength = textBox.SelectionLength;
    String newText = String.Empty;
    int count = 0;
    foreach (Char c in textBox.Text.ToCharArray())
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(c) || Char.IsControl(c) || (c == '0' && count == 0))
        {
            newText += c;
            if (c == '0')
                count += 1;

        }
    }
    textBox.Text = newText;
    textBox.SelectionStart = selectionStart <= textBox.Text.Length ? selectionStart : textBox.Text.Length;
}
```

Complete Code is Available At PasteBin..

http://pastebin.com/Zr1ZckJr

Its the Complete CS file.

Comment: Fax number is being stored as a number, not a numeric string, so the leading zero has no meaning. You should consider changing datatype from numeric to string.

Comment: @shree.pat18
Thankyou sir for reply, but i tried to see in properties in Visual Studio for datatype, couldn't find any option.
how to do that, i mean change its datatype..

Comment: In addition to the comment from @shree.pat18, I'd suspect that you have something in the text changed event that's preventing the leading zero - possibly by doing the conversion to an int64 as per the code fragment you've provided.  What's the code for event `tbFax_TextChanged`?

Comment: shree.pat18 is talking about this line: `fax = Int64.Parse(tbFax.Text);`.  Your leading zero is gone here.

Comment: @BrendanGreen
Sir, There is another field in the same form `tbContactNo`. with that 0 do works.. i am not sure how. i tried to compare there code to see if there is any change that i can do to fix the Fax textbox also. but couldn't find any.

Comment: @SizzlingCode we need to see the code for the event handlers.

Comment: @BrendanGreen
`Int64.Parse(tbContactNo.Text);` How comes this works with initial 0 but not the `Int64.Parse(tbFax.Text);`.
plus i think you are right. that there is something wrong with textchanged as it dont allow me to input 0

Comment: Because that code is in what I presume to be a save method, meaning that the leading zero is stripped out on save (check your DB to see what's happening).  Ultimately, phone numbers are **not numbers** - they are text.

Comment: As Brendan said, we can help you if you share the code. Please edit your question with the text changed event handler code for both Fax and Contact No fields.

Comment: @BrendanGreen
Many Thanks For Helping me out, Updated The Question with the code of Event Handler..

Comment: @shree.pat18
Question Updated sir.

Comment: Best solution is to save your fax number and phone numbers like this as string not as number.

Comment: @shreesha
i tried to convert to string..
initialized with `string fax = "0";`

But in above code i get error in `dtAgent.Fax  = fax;`. Where Error States `"Cannot implicitly convert type string to long"` ??
So kind of stucked with Numeric..

Comment: error is clear.go to your dtAgent class and change the type of Fax to string.

Comment: @shreesha
its ok, i tried long.parse(fax). Error is gone, But still the same problem i am not able to input 0 in start..
its not the problem with save button. It has something to do with the textbox event or something as i press 0 in very start of text box, it dont work.. 0 dont show up. but after any other digit 0 works fine.

i cant press 0..???

Comment: check your FaxNo property?i think there must be some validation going on to prevent zero.check this.this code will not allow you to enter zero at beginning `set 
            {
                if (value.ToString()=="0")
              { 
                    fax= ""; 
               }
            else
            {
                fax= value;
            }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues and a potential design flaw in the application.

**First**, you need to be treating phone / fax numbers as `string` data instead of numbers.  Think about it - phone numbers can have parentheses (e.g. `(03)95551234`), they can have spaces (e.g. `555 1234`), they can have dashes (e.g. `555-1234`) and so on.

**Second**, now that you are treating phone / fax numbers as strings, you don't need to try to convert them to numbers.

Doing this: `Int64.Parse(tbContactNo.Text);` will throw an exception if, for example, you have spaces, parentheses or dashes in `tbContactNo`.

**Third**, you need to update your database table so that the fields that you are storing these numbers inside of are text fields, and not number fields.  For example, use an `NVARCHAR(20)` instead of `INT`.

The side effect of this datatype change is that fields like `dtAgent.Fax` will need to be changed from being a `long` to a `string`.  This will fix your "`Cannot implicitly convert type string to long`" error.

**Finally**, depending on the requirements of your application, the event handler on the phone / fax number `TextBox` controls can either be removed, or updated to handle the inputs in a better way.

If you want to enforce a particular format for phone / fax numbers, you'd be better of using a masked input, such as provided by the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You should store your fax/phone number as text. But if you insist on keeping it as a number and have problem with the before zeros which skipped in the Parsing instruction; you can keep the length of your fax number string, and when you need it, add zeros before the rest of your integer number:

```
var faxNumber = Int64.Parse(tbFax.Text);
var faxNumberLenght = tbFax.Text.Length;
```

and of course the number of zero digits with calculate as:

```
var zeroCounts = faxNumberLenght - (faxNumber.ToString().Length);
```

Comment: That's a poor solution.  Every time that the number is read from the database, it'd have to be transformed using this logic (which also requires an additional field for storage).  This seems to be very error prone.

Comment: @BrendanGreen: You'r right, but some times it's not this much critical and a poor but so simple and understandable solution could be helpful. anyway, I think your answer is quite a good one! :)